# How to do event-handling in React, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, events, html-select

I have three different selections and I want to store each selected and current option its own state. I also want when the user changes option to store that on the state.

[image: Here html output]

Here is my states:

```
this.state = {
    header: [
        'genre',
        'sold',
        'income'
    ],
    chartData: [
        'Line',
        'Bar',
        'AreaChart',
        'PieChart',
        'ScatterChart'
    ],
    axisX: '',
    axisY: '',
    selectedLine: ''
}
```

Here is my "**handleChart**" function. Basically what I am trying to do here is, when the component loads I want to store whatever current options on the state and when the user changes or selects new option, I want to store that on the state too.

```
handleChart = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const value = e.target.value;
    if(value === 'line'){
        // First selection: contains >>> different chart names
        this.setState({selectedLine: value})
    }else if(value === 'genre'){
        // Second selection: contains >>> different headers
        this.setState({axisX: value})
    }else if(value === 'income'){
        // Third selection: contains >>> different headers
        this.setState({axisY: value)
    }
}
```

My App.js

```
<div className="App">
    <div style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
        <span>Chart type: </span>
        <select onChange={this.handleChart} style={{marginRight: '15px'}}>
            {this.state.chartData.map((k, v) => (
                <option name="line" key={k} value="line">{k}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
        <span>x-axis: </span>
        <select onChange={this.handleChart} style={{marginRight: '15px'}}>
            {this.state.header.map((k, v) => (
                <option name="xaxis" key={k} value={k}>{k}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
        <span>y-axis: </span>
        <select onChange={this.handleChart} style={{marginRight: '15px'}}>
            {this.state.header.map((k, v) => (
                <option name="yaxis" key={k} value={k}>{k}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of problems you have?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have a way to update state based on changing the value of an input, however your current approach can be improved to be more robust. You can give each input a `name` attribute and then have the name correspond to the variable name within `state` so you don't need a bunch of `if/else if` blocks.

To have inputs take values from state, set the `value` attribute on the `input`/`select`/etc (rather than on `option`) equal to the value from `state` that you want to use.

Here is an updated version of `handleChart`:

```js
handleChart = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value;
    });
}
```

And updated App.js:

```js
render() {
    const { axisX, axisY, selectedLine } = this.state;

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
                <span>Chart type: </span>
                <select name="selectedLine" value={ selectedLine }  onChange={this.handleChart} style={{marginRight: '15px'}}>
                    {this.state.chartData.map((k, v) => (
                        <option name="line" key={k} value={v}>{v}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
                <span>x-axis: </span>
                <select name="axisX" value={ axisX } onChange={this.handleChart} style={{marginRight: '15px'}}>
                    {this.state.header.map((k, v) => (
                        <option name="xaxis" key={k} value={v}>{v}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
                <span>y-axis: </span>
                <select name="axisY" value={ axisY } onChange={this.handleChart} style={{marginRight: '15px'}}>
                    {this.state.header.map((k, v) => (
                        <option name="yaxis" key={k} value={v}>{v}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```